# How to store user's chat details in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, chat, nsdocumentdirectory

How to store user's chat details in coredata. If the user has ten contacts and with each contact he has send/ receive messages, images, audio, video, contacts, location etc. How will I save these details in coredata. I think it has something to do with coredata relationships, but I'm not familiar with it. Is there any drawback if I save these details in documents directory? I'm using xcode 7.2. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read core data details https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html

Comment: This question is too broad

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the plist? This is a great tutorial reference for chat apps for objective c. I hope this helps. The author does a great job explaining it. Its a lengthy read but well worth it, https://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1